# Compare number when there is a colon prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set a class if the string in the element below has a value higher than 0.

The script works if I remove the strong part and the colon, but I can´t control this so how do i targets this?

Script:

```
$('.stockinfo.col4').filter(function(index){
return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 0;
}).addClass("instocktest");
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 0<span></span></div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 50<span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.textContent` to get the text without any HTML tags. And remove everything except the digits before converting to a number

```js
$('.stockinfo.col4').filter(function(index) {
  return parseInt(this.textContent.replace(/\D/g, '')) > 0;
}).addClass("instocktest");
```

```css
.instocktest {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 0<span></span>
</div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 50<span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't see that the DIV contained more text before the colon. I've changed it to use a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
$('.stockinfo.col4').filter(function(index){
    var number=$(this).find('strong')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
    return parseInt(number) > 0;
}).addClass("instocktest");
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/ok57epge/1/)

Comment: @user3344734,  For me it is working perfectly. I updated answer with fiddle. It seems you forgot to include jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can check if `text()` yields content in your `div`

```
$('.stockinfo.col4').filter(function(index){
return parseInt($(this).text()) > 0;
}).addClass("instocktest");
```

Comment: Why to try this? What have you done? Where is real test about this?

Comment: @Justinas what so exceptional change you see here ? it is the use of text() method that is added.

Comment: `this.text()` should be `$(this).text()`, since `text()` is a jQuery method and `this` is a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match if there is more than one 0 in content:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stockinfo.col4').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text().match(/0/g).length >= 2;
  }).addClass("instocktest");
})
```

```css
.instocktest {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 0<span></span>
</div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 5000<span></span>
</div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 50 and 00<span></span>
</div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 50 and 0<span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP meant to say "more than zero" rather than "more than one zero".

Comment: Yeah - Maybe I was unclear - connexo is right, this doesnt work for me.

Comment: OP just want to see if some content is present in the div?